# SELECT ProcessId unexpected behaviour inside HTA

Tags: vbscript

First of all, thanks for reading.

I have a HTA to centralize some repetitive task.
Login into several servers via ssh and send multiple commands is one of them.

This code is working like a charm inside a vbs file

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, WMI, wql, process

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

wql = "SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'putty.exe'"
dim cmd : cmd=InputBox("Enter command")
For Each process In WMI.ExecQuery(wql)
    Shell.AppActivate process.ProcessId
    Shell.SendKeys cmd & " {ENTER}"
Next
```

But this equivalent, inside a HTA only sends the command to one or two windows.

```
sub sendToPuttyWindow(cmd)
    Dim Shell, WMI, wql, process

    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

    wql = "SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'putty.exe'"

    For Each process In WMI.ExecQuery(wql)
        Shell.AppActivate process.ProcessId
        Shell.SendKeys cmd & " {ENTER}"
    Next
end sub
```

Currently I'm calling the vbs file from the hta, but I would like to maintain the HTA file as independent as possible.

Could you please help me?

Comment: I would check the `SendKeys` API, both for a wait until processed option, for debugging, and generally, as it is known to have "complex" issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `SendKeys` for automating PuTTY. It sends all emulated keystrokes to the current foreground window, whatever that may be. If you need to run several commands in a row: use [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the PuTTY suite. It was built for this exact purpose.

```
plink -ssh -batch -m file user@host
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know plink, and I use it for other purposes. But for this case, what I need exactly is to send keystrokes to all the putty windows. There are programs that do this kind of stuff, putty command sender is one example. I need to log in several servers, using a interactive session, and some times I would like to send keystrokes to all the opened putty windows. I don't understand the hysteria about the SendKeys method.

Comment: @Danielo515 The problem with `SendKeys` is that its keystrokes go to the current foreground window, **whatever that may be**. VBScript cannot reliably send keystrokes to a particular window.

Comment: The Documentation you linked says this: Specifies which application to activate. This can be a string containing the title of the application (as it appears in the title bar) or the application's Process ID. As you can see, Process ID is a valid input. As I said, this is working like a charm from and external vbs file. Thank for your effort anyway

Comment: Hmm... you're right. I have no idea why I failed to notice the "or the application's Process ID" part. Anyway, I removed the incorrect note from my answer.